# Turtlebot navigation stack "occdist_scale"

Tags: ros, navigation, turtlebot, turtlebot-navigation, obstacle-avoidance

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is with reference to the tutorial "Setup the Navigation Stack for TurtleBot" http://www.ros.org/wiki/turtlebot_navigation/Tutorials/Setup%20the%20Navigation%20Stack%20for%20TurtleBot
In this article, under the sections Move base/Planner/Cost computing biases, "occdist_scale" is mentioned to make the robot more afraid of obstacles. I looked in turtlebot_navigation/param/base_local_planner_params.yaml and could not find any such parameter. Am I looking at the right file, or is this some outdated info on the wiki? Can anyone suggest a way to increase the turtlebot's 'fear' of obstacles when it is autonomously navigating a known map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67504/turtlebot-navigation-stack-%22occdist_scale%22/) by [turtlebotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/4957/turtlebotnewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2013-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You are right, occdist_scale is not set for Turtlebot navigation, so it takes the default value (0.01). But you can set it, of course.

The two other weights for the cost function are set as

- goal_distance_bias: 0.8
- path_distance_bias: 0.6

but I think they are actually ignored. I have checked the code (hydro) and they are used by DWA planner, but no by the generic base_local_planner. So they are never used with turtlebot, to my understanding, regardless the local planner you use (dwa boolean parameter). **A confirmation will be very appreciated!**

I have changed the base_local_planner wiki accordingly. I hope I'm right...

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [turtlebotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/4957/turtlebotnewbie/) on 2013-07-17**:
Thanks. I realized that the yaml file does not specify all the parameters. It takes default values for most of the parameters. The list of all parameters that can be set in the base_local_planner_params.yaml are given is section 4.2 of the following link: http://www.ros.org/wiki/base_local_planner

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-07-23**:
Btw, on hydro we have updated most turtlebot navigation parameters